# Select where column not in an other one 2 times

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have table like this called "table"

```
+--------------+
| id | c1 | c2 |
+--------------+
| 1  | a  | 0  |
| 2  | b  | 1  |
| 3  | c  | 1  |
| 4  | d  | 2  |
| 5  | e  | 2  |
| 6  | f  | 3  |
| 7  | g  | 4  |
| 8  | h  | 5  |
+--------------+
```

I want to SELECT 'c1' FROM 'table' WHERE 'id' not in 'c2' 2 times

Comment: Please give desired results to go along with the example data so we can figure out what you are asking.

Comment: is it some sort of adjacency relationship, a child-parent relation between id and c2?

Comment: Do you mean 2 times or 2 or more times?

Comment: @Peter - Please let the OP clarify their own question thank you. The original wording is pretty vague and ambiguous. By giving desired results you steer everyone towards your specific interpretation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN 
(SELECT c2 FROM table GROUP BY c2 HAVING Count(c2) = 2)
```

Comment: Something along these lines seems likely but do they want exactly 2?

Comment: He can change the COUNT(c2) = 2 by anything else, don't think he needs help for that kind of clause :)

Comment: The original question said 2 times.  If its 2 or greater, this query is easily modified to match.

Comment: I want 5 but writing to is better in getting help...
@tsabz my database will be 3905 at least and whe I run this query it takes about 10.8 Seconds .. so is there anyway to do it faster?

Answer (score 1):

**SKIP IDS WHICH ARE NOT IN C2 AT ALL:**

```
SELECT d.id, d.c1, g.gcount
FROM 
(
   SELECT c2 as gc2, COUNT(*) as gcount
   FROM @data
   GROUP BY c2
) g
INNER JOIN @data d ON d.id = g.gc2 AND gcount != 2
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
id | c1 | gcount
3  | c  |   1
4  | d  |   1
5  | e  |   1
```

**INCLUDE IDS WHICH NOT IN C2:**

```
SELECT d.id, d.c1, ISNULL(g.gcount, 0) as gcount
FROM 
(
   SELECT c2 as gc2, COUNT(*) as gcount
   FROM @data
   GROUP BY c2
) g
RIGHT JOIN @data d ON d.id = g.gc2
WHERE gcount IS NULL OR g.gcount != 2
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
id  c1  gcount
3   c   1
4   d   1
5   e   1
6   f   0
7   g   0
8   h   0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.*
from table t
left outer join (
    select c2, count(*) as Count
    from table
    group by c2
) tc on t.id = tc.c2
where Count is null or Count < 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  t1.c1 
from
  t t1,
  t t2
where 
  t1.id = t2.c2
group by
  t1.c1
having 
  count(t2.c2) != 2;
```